# Make How to Format available in the app

Tags: feature-request, markdown, asking-questions, ios-app

Users unfamiliar with Stack Exchange may not realize it isn't entirely WYSIWYG. In some cases (once we get out of alpha of course!) it's possible the app is their only exposure to SE.

I propose the "How to Format" help be made available in the app. One option might be as a button at the bottom of the preview page:

> [image: mockup of how to format button]

---

Additionally, [preview should be shown automatically before posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228760/show-preview-before-posting-question-in-app).