# Show preview before posting question in app

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, ios-app, markdown-preview

Users unfamiliar with Stack Exchange may not realize it isn't entirely WYSIWYG. In some cases (once we get out of alpha of course!) it's possible the app is their only exposure to SE.

On the desktop site, a preview is shown below the question. In the app, that preview is an optional button.

#### I propose the following logic:

If a user writes a question, and doesn't preview, the Submit button should only be accessible from the preview page. If they've already clicked Preview at least once before, the Submit button should be available on the drafting page.

I'd be open to discussion about whether and when this could be bypassed for higher rep users.

---

Additionally, [How to Format should be made available in the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228759/make-how-to-format-available-in-the-app)